# pyqtgraph GLScatterPlotItem with cubes instead of spheres for points

Tags: python, plot, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to do a scatter plot in 3d, but I need the points to represented as squares instead of circles.  I have a working version in Octave with

```
scatter3(xPos,yPos,zPos,size,values,'s','filled')
```

However, I need to do the same thing in Python, but I do not think point symbol is an option in GLScatterPlotItem as it is with ScatterPlotItem in pyqtgraph.

Does anyone know how to do it in pyqtgraph or any other plotting modules?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using voxels.

The variable "voxmap" below is a 3d array (x,y,z) with a value 1 being set a various points. For more reading check out: https://terbium.io/2017/12/matplotlib-3d/

eg. voxmap[10, 11, 2] = 1.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.voxels(voxmap, edgecolor='k')
ax.set_xlim(voxmap.shape[0], 0)
ax.set_ylim(0, voxmap.shape[1])
# add a bit to z-axis height for visualization
ax.set_zlim(0, voxmap.shape[2]+20)
```

[image: Voxel plot using Matplot lib]